# Is there a way to disable the pushpins in OpenGTS?

Tags: java, javascript, xml, ant, gps

I want OpenGTS to display only the red path that it shows beneath the pushpins, and not them.

Better yet: it would be perfect if I could achieve to make it display a pushpin only in the beginning and end of a given path.

Is it possible without hacking the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the new version of OpenGTS (2.3.8) brings this feature. From the ChangeLog:

```
Version 2.3.8 [2011/10/10]
- NEW: Added additional StatusCodes.
- NEW: Added "map.showPushpins" property to MapProvider section to allow disabling the display of pushpins on the map.
- NEW: Added support for daylight-savings-time zone names to "DateTime.java".
- UPD: Added GeozoneID support to "GPSEvent.java"
- DCS: taip - Added estimated odometer calculation, and simulated geozone support.
- DCS: sipgear - default listen port changed from 31270 to 31170.
- DCS: icare - default listen port changed from 31260 to 31160.
- FIX: Fix memory leak issue in "OpenLayers.js" (thanks to YanXu "stelzbock")
```